Div height does not extend in pages other than the first one
I'm using MPDF. I set content div height to 100% so that it extends to the end of page. It works great on the first page. However in case the content is lengthy that needs to extend to more than one page this property seems not work on pages other than the first one.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <style>
    @page {
        sheet-size: A4;
        margin-top: 40mm;
        margin-bottom: 20mm;

        odd-header-name: html_header;
        odd-footer-name: html_footer;
    }
  </style>
  
</head>

<body>

  <htmlpageheader name="header">
    <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 30mm; border:1px solid black; text-align: center;">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
  </htmlpageheader>

  <htmlpagefooter name="footer">
    <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 10mm; border:1px solid black;">
      <table width="100%" style="vertical-align: bottom; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">
        <tr>
          <td width="33%"></td>
          <td width="34%" align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;">Page {PAGENO} of {nbpg}</td>
          <td width="33%"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </htmlpagefooter>

  <div id="content" style="background-color: orange; border:1px solid black; height: 100%;">
    <p>1. Arsenal Football Club, established in 1886, is one of the most storied and successful football clubs in England. Based in Islington, North London, the club has a rich history characterized by numerous domestic and international achievements. Arsenal has won the English Premier League multiple times and boasts a significant number of FA Cup victories, making it one of the most decorated clubs in English football. The team's iconic red and white colors, along with its passionate fan base, contribute to its reputation as a formidable force in the sport.</p>
    <p>2. The club's home ground, the Emirates Stadium, opened in 2006 and has a seating capacity of over 60,000, providing a modern and vibrant atmosphere for supporters. Arsenal is known for its attacking style of play and has produced many legendary players, including Thierry Henry, Dennis Bergkamp, and Tony Adams, who have left an indelible mark on the club's legacy. The team's commitment to developing young talent through its academy has also been a hallmark of its philosophy, ensuring a continuous influx of skilled players.</p>
    <p>3. Arsenal's rivalry with clubs such as Tottenham Hotspur, known as the North London Derby, adds to the excitement of the Premier League. The club has a global following, with fans from various countries passionately supporting the team. As Arsenal continues to compete at the highest levels of English and European football, it remains dedicated to its core values of excellence, community engagement, and sportsmanship, striving to add more trophies to its illustrious history.</p>
    <p>1. Arsenal Football Club, established in 1886, is one of the most storied and successful football clubs in England. Based in Islington, North London, the club has a rich history characterized by numerous domestic and international achievements. Arsenal has won the English Premier League multiple times and boasts a significant number of FA Cup victories, making it one of the most decorated clubs in English football. The team's iconic red and white colors, along with its passionate fan base, contribute to its reputation as a formidable force in the sport.</p>
    <p>2. The club's home ground, the Emirates Stadium, opened in 2006 and has a seating capacity of over 60,000, providing a modern and vibrant atmosphere for supporters. Arsenal is known for its attacking style of play and has produced many legendary players, including Thierry Henry, Dennis Bergkamp, and Tony Adams, who have left an indelible mark on the club's legacy. The team's commitment to developing young talent through its academy has also been a hallmark of its philosophy, ensuring a continuous influx of skilled players.</p>
    <p>3. Arsenal's rivalry with clubs such as Tottenham Hotspur, known as the North London Derby, adds to the excitement of the Premier League. The club has a global following, with fans from various countries passionately supporting the team. As Arsenal continues to compete at the highest levels of English and European football, it remains dedicated to its core values of excellence, community engagement, and sportsmanship, striving to add more trophies to its illustrious history.</p>
    <p>1. Arsenal Football Club, established in 1886, is one of the most storied and successful football clubs in England. Based in Islington, North London, the club has a rich history characterized by numerous domestic and international achievements. Arsenal has won the English Premier League multiple times and boasts a significant number of FA Cup victories, making it one of the most decorated clubs in English football. The team's iconic red and white colors, along with its passionate fan base, contribute to its reputation as a formidable force in the sport.</p>
    <p>2. The club's home ground, the Emirates Stadium, opened in 2006 and has a seating capacity of over 60,000, providing a modern and vibrant atmosphere for supporters. Arsenal is known for its attacking style of play and has produced many legendary players, including Thierry Henry, Dennis Bergkamp, and Tony Adams, who have left an indelible mark on the club's legacy. The team's commitment to developing young talent through its academy has also been a hallmark of its philosophy, ensuring a continuous influx of skilled players.</p>
    <p>3. Arsenal's rivalry with clubs such as Tottenham Hotspur, known as the North London Derby, adds to the excitement of the Premier League. The club has a global following, with fans from various countries passionately supporting the team. As Arsenal continues to compete at the highest levels of English and European football, it remains dedicated to its core values of excellence, community engagement, and sportsmanship, striving to add more trophies to its illustrious history.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


"htmlpageheader" ?

I'm using MPDF @mplungjan

You have some non-standard HTML tags and you tagged this with php and mpdf but none of that is included in the question or markup. You are going to have to explain that. In addition, the align attribute has been obsolete for over 20 years.

Remove the height: 100%; from the content div and allow it to take its natural height based on the content. The browser will automatically handle the content's extension across multiple pages.
